# Go Template - calling another template with multiple parameters

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm using an application that is getting me some data, and then renders a config file based on a given Go Template. You basically pass a template you've made as a parameter, and app does it's job with it. The template is getting bigger and bigger, so I wanted to wrap some common stuff into sub-templates (I mean, {{ define x }}). The problem I'm occuring is that the sub-template should be passed serveral parameters, which are not a part of my 'dot', and I can't really find a way to do this in Go.

The best answer I've found is to write some 'dict' function myself, and then use it inside the template, but that would mean I basically need to fork the whole application I'm using to render the template, do like 10-15 line changes, and then use this modified versions, which is a nonsense.

I'm wondering if there's any real solution for my problem without having to do some crazy forking and writing custom methods on application side?

Edit:
I've already checked [Calling a template with several pipeline parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276173/calling-a-template-with-several-pipeline-parameters) before, although it's not answering my question, since I need a way to do this using only template file.

Comment: A custom function is required to pass multiple parameters to a template. 
 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276173/calling-a-template-with-several-pipeline-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a template with several pipeline parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276173/calling-a-template-with-several-pipeline-parameters)